# Null Pointer Exception in fragment on create android?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-activity, fragment

I am getting the following exception when I am running my app in Android Version 2.2.1.

```
     FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.vfc.mardemo1/com.vfc.register.RegUserDetailActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2669)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2685)  
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:126)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2038)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4633)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)


     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
     at com.vfc.register.RegUserDetailActivity$PlaceholderFragment.onCreateView(RegUserDetailActivity.java:65)
     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:570)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1129)
     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:3781)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2642)
```

There is no code at line no 65 and my activity contains only 63 LOC.

Can someone help me out here.

The app is running fine in Icecream sandwich and above.

Here is the activity code

```
    public class RegisterActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
    setContentView(R.layout.register_activity);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
        // do nothing
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.register_fragment,
                container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

public void onReg(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,
            RegUserDetailActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

}

Comment: Go in onCreateView and put the code here.

Comment: ^ And specify which line is line 65.

Comment: paste your code here.

Comment: Why not simply debug through `onCreateView()` and find out what's null?

Comment: I think   View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.register_fragment,container, false);  this line creating problem. Debug your code here.

Comment: Hi your logcat shows error occurs in RegUserDetailActivity ** com.vfc.register.RegUserDetailActivity$PlaceholderFragment.onCreateView(RegUserDetailActivity.java:65) ** not in registerActivity. please updated RegUserDetailActivity

Comment: That was the point I was missing thank you. Found the error.